# Trying to create Personal Data Resource in Wolfram Cloud Notebook

Tags: bugs, wolfram-cloud, wolfram-data-framework

I am trying to create a Personal Data Resource from within a Wolfram Cloud notebook. I'm following the instructions at:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/SetUpAPersonalDataResource.html

I don't have a desktop version of Mathematica so I'm using Wolfram Cloud notebook and running the command: `CreateNotebook["DataResource"]`

I've tried using Google Chrome and Internet Explorer and Android app. The notebook starts opening a dialog box but the fields scroll off the top of the page leaving all fields inaccessible:
[image: screenshot]

**Update** Wolfram have fixed the scrolling problem but it still doesn't work.

Using the Wolfram Cloud in Chrome on Windows 10. I ran CreateNotebook["DataResource"]. After filling in the Name/Title field I had to rewrite the code in the sections Content Elements as I could not enter text into the provided placeholders. Finally evaluating the code in Create Resource Object produces $Failed.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: I've submitted this to Wolfram and they admit it's not working as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wolfram let me know that this is not supported in the Wolfram cloud!